# Changing the filtering behavior in OpenCart

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce, opencart

I'm using the default filtering behavior of OpenCart in [my shop](http://belfurniture.com/king-mattress-sets). The way the filtering works, when you select multiple filters, it shows any product that meet any of those selected criteria. I need to change this behavior so it only shows products that meet ALL the selected criteria.

I have narrowed down the responsible function to be inside `catalog/model/catalog/product.php`

Below is the entire function. Any clue how I would change the logic?

```
public function getProducts($data = array()) {

            if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
                $customer_group_id = $this->customer->getCustomerGroupId();
            } else {
                $customer_group_id = $this->config->get('config_customer_group_id');
            }   

            $sql = "SELECT p.product_id, (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special"; 

            if (!empty($data['filter_category_id'])) {
                if (!empty($data['filter_sub_category'])) {
                    $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category_path cp LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c ON (cp.category_id = p2c.category_id)";         
                } else {
                    $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c";
                }

                if (!empty($data['filter_filter'])) {
                    $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_filter pf ON (p2c.product_id = pf.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (pf.product_id = p.product_id)";
                } else {
                    $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id)";
                }
            } else {
                $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p";
            }

            $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) WHERE pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'";

            if (!empty($data['filter_category_id'])) {
                if (!empty($data['filter_sub_category'])) {
                    $sql .= " AND cp.path_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_category_id'] . "'"; 
                } else {
                    $sql .= " AND p2c.category_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_category_id'] . "'";            
                }   

                if (!empty($data['filter_filter'])) {
                    $implode = array();

                    $filters = explode(',', $data['filter_filter']);

                    foreach ($filters as $filter_id) {
                        $implode[] = (int)$filter_id;
                    }

                    $sql .= " AND pf.filter_id IN (" . implode(',', $implode) . ")";                
                }
            }   

            if (!empty($data['filter_name']) || !empty($data['filter_tag'])) {
                $sql .= " AND (";

                if (!empty($data['filter_name'])) {
                    $implode = array();

                    $words = explode(' ', trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $data['filter_name'])));

                    foreach ($words as $word) {
                        $implode[] = "pd.name LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($word) . "%'";
                    }

                    if ($implode) {
                        $sql .= " " . implode(" AND ", $implode) . "";
                    }

                    if (!empty($data['filter_description'])) {
                        $sql .= " OR pd.description LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_name']) . "%'";
                    }
                }

                if (!empty($data['filter_name']) && !empty($data['filter_tag'])) {
                    $sql .= " OR ";
                }

                if (!empty($data['filter_tag'])) {
                    $sql .= "pd.tag LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_tag']) . "%'";
                }

                if (!empty($data['filter_name'])) {
                    $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.model) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
                }

                if (!empty($data['filter_name'])) {
                    $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.sku) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
                }   

                if (!empty($data['filter_name'])) {
                    $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.upc) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
                }       

                if (!empty($data['filter_name'])) {
                    $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.ean) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
                }

                if (!empty($data['filter_name'])) {
                    $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.jan) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
                }

                if (!empty($data['filter_name'])) {
                    $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.isbn) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
                }       

                if (!empty($data['filter_name'])) {
                    $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.mpn) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
                }

                $sql .= ")";
            }

            if (!empty($data['filter_manufacturer_id'])) {
                $sql .= " AND p.manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_manufacturer_id'] . "'";
            }

            if (!empty($data['filter_include_in_create_room'])) {
                $sql .= " AND p.include_in_create_room = '" . (int)$data['filter_include_in_create_room'] . "'";
            }

            $sql .= " GROUP BY p.product_id";

            $sort_data = array(
                'pd.name',
                'p.model',
                'p.quantity',
                'p.price',
                'rating',
                'p.sort_order',
                'p.date_added'
            );  

            if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
                if ($data['sort'] == 'pd.name' || $data['sort'] == 'p.model') {
                    $sql .= " ORDER BY LCASE(" . $data['sort'] . ")";
                } elseif ($data['sort'] == 'p.price') {
                    $sql .= " ORDER BY (CASE WHEN special IS NOT NULL THEN special WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount ELSE p.price END)";
                } else {
                    $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $data['sort'];
                }
            } else {
                $sql .= " ORDER BY p.sort_order";   
            }

            if (isset($data['order']) && ($data['order'] == 'DESC')) {
                $sql .= " DESC, LCASE(pd.name) DESC";
            } else {
                $sql .= " ASC, LCASE(pd.name) ASC";
            }

            if (isset($data['start']) || isset($data['limit'])) {
                if ($data['start'] < 0) {
                    $data['start'] = 0;
                }               

                if ($data['limit'] < 1) {
                    $data['limit'] = 20;
                }   

                $sql .= " LIMIT " . (int)$data['start'] . "," . (int)$data['limit'];
            }

            $product_data = array();

            $query = $this->db->query($sql);

            foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
                $product_data[$result['product_id']] = $this->getProduct($result['product_id']);
            }

            return $product_data;
        }
```

Comment: How large is your data set? Thousands of items or just dozens? I ask because the largest mattress provider appears to have ca. 100 products.

Comment: What have you tried? In general you will need to change `or` to `and` in the sql query.

Comment: @Strawberry we have about 1600 products.

Comment: Hm, even so, I think I'd still be tempted to just return the entire data set and handle the filtering in php or javascript.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to have OR logic between attributes in the same group and AND logic between attributes in different groups you should:

go to "catalog\model\catalog" edit product.php

The function you need to edit is public function getProducts($data = array(), $get_all = FALSE) {

At the start of the function specify these variables: $validimi = false; $filter_groups = array();

Find this code:

```
if (!empty($data['filter_filter'])) {
                $implode = array();

                $filters = explode(',', $data['filter_filter']);

                foreach ($filters as $filter_id) {
                    $implode[] = (int)$filter_id;
                }

                $sql .= " AND pf.filter_id IN (" . implode(',', $implode) . ")";
}
```

and add this piece just before $sql .= " AND pf.filter_id IN (" . implode(',', $implode) . ")";

```
        $sql_check = "SELECT DISTINCT (filter_group_id) FROM  " . DB_PREFIX . "filter WHERE filter_id IN (" . implode(',', $implode) . ") ";    
        $query_check = $this->db->query($sql_check);
        $filter_groups = array();
        foreach ($query_check->rows as $result) {
            $filter_groups[$result['filter_group_id']] = array();
        }

        if(count($filter_groups) > 1){
            $validimi = true;               
        }else{
            $validimi = false;
        }
```

finally find this piece of code in the function i specified:

$sql .= " GROUP BY p.product_id";

and change it to:

```
  If( $validimi ) {
$sql .= "GROUP BY p.product_id HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT pf.filter_id)=".count($filter_groups);
}else{

    $sql .= " GROUP BY p.product_id";

}
```

now try your filters they should work fine, this is what i created and used on my own stores but with opencart version 1.5.5.1 but i think it will work fine in your case too. The logic is clear so in case that this code does not help you, you can use the logic to create your own :).

Hope i helped.

Comment: I think it will work only when all the filters selected are of different groups. Then and only, count filter id will match with the count filter groups. So OR condition to be applied in case of filters from same groups will not work.

Comment: Got a bit clarity on the logic. It will work in most of the cases, only case where it will fail is when you have multiple filters from a filter group assigned to one product itself and then the same list of filters is being applied and searched for in the frontend.